# ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction

Tags: vb.net, executenonquery

I'm facing a problem with executing queries through command text. What I want to do is to delete the data from data-grid and database and reinsert them upon users' selection.

The error is:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.

Here is the code where I delete:

```
Private Sub DeleteRecord(ByVal month As Integer)

    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = Connection
    cmd.Transaction = transaction
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[MEC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS] WHERE MecMonth = '" & DTP_From.Value.Month & "'"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

and by using this button I'm generating data:

```
Private Sub btn_Generate_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles btn_Generate.ItemClick

    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = Connection

    Try
        If Mcount > 0 Then
            If MecMonth = DTP_From.Value.Month Then
                If MsgBox("Do you want to delete and regenerate data for the same month?", MsgBoxStyle.Question & MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirmation") = MsgBoxResult.No Then Exit Sub
                'cmd = New SqlCommand(" DELETE FROM [dbo].[MEC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS] WHERE MecMonth = '" & DTP_From.Value.Month & "'", Connection)

                DeleteRecord(DTP_From.Value.Month)
            End If

        Else
            DeleteRecord(DTP_From.Value.Month)
            'cmd = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [dbo].[MEC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS] WHERE MecMonth = '" & DTP_From.Value.Month & "'", Connection)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception  
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    INSERT_MEC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS()

End Sub
```

and here is how I insert data:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Me.Grid_Data.DataSource = table
'Dim transaction As SqlClient.SqlTransaction

cmd.Connection = Connection
cmd.Transaction = transaction

Try

    For i As Integer = 0 To Grid_Data.Rows.Count - 1
        SERVICEITEMFID = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        C_FullName_Eng = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        C_FullName_Arb = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        C_PhoneNo = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        C_PhoneNo2 = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        Plate_Nbr = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        PlateCode_Desc = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
        CodeID = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
            SERVICEID = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value
        COLLECTIONDATE = Grid_Data.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value
        MecMonth = DTP_From.Value.Month

        sql = "INSERT INTO MEC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS (SERVICEITEMFID ,C_FullName_Eng ,C_FullName_Arb,C_PhoneNo,C_PhoneNo2 ,Plate_Nbr ,PlateCode_Desc ,CodeID,COLLECTIONDATE ,SERVICEID,MecMonth)"
        sql &= " values('" & SERVICEITEMFID & "','" & C_FullName_Eng & "','" & C_FullName_Arb & "','" & C_PhoneNo & "','" & C_PhoneNo2 & "','" & Plate_Nbr & "','" & PlateCode_Desc & "','" & CodeID & "','" & Format(COLLECTIONDATE, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "','" & SERVICEID & "','" & DTP_From.Value.Month & "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, Connection)
        transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    transaction.Commit()
Catch ex As Exception
    transaction.Rollback()
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
transaction.Dispose()
```

Comment: Did you try to comment out the `cmd.Transaction = transaction`?

Comment: @muffi yes I did check how i insert data to the db

Comment: If you want to use transaction, the right way is: `transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction` and at the end, you do `transaction.Commit()`.

Comment: The only way that exception occurs is when you have a pending transaction (i.e. haven't called a commit/rollback on a command you have executed) and then you try to execute another command without assigning it to the SAME transaction. You have to either create a new transaction and commit it each time you execute a command, or pass the transaction reference along and assign it to each command.

Comment: @soohoonigan please can you check the insert sub and tell me what did I do wrong

Comment: @soohoonigan im using transaction only once

Answer (score 0):

You have a `FOR Loop` for the insert. Before the loop finishes you try to create a new transaction and the previous one is left open without committing it. Therefore, on the next iteration you get the error. Make sure you commit when the loop ends. 
Try moving the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` below the `Next` statement